How to do terrain deformation in unity
I'm making a game where I have a bomb dropping mechanic. I want to make sure that when a bomb explodes, I will have a crater left from the explosion on the terrain. The crater is not just a picture, but specifically so that the terrain is deformed.
I tried this code
public void DeformTerrain(Vector3 pos, float deformationAmount, float deformationRadius)
{
Terrain terrain = GetComponent();
 int posXInTerrain = (int)((pos.x / terrain.terrainData.size.x) * terrain.terrainData.heightmapResolution);
 int posZInTerrain = (int)((pos.z / terrain.terrainData.size.z) * terrain.terrainData.heightmapResolution);

 float[,] heights = terrain.terrainData.GetHeights(0, 0, terrain.terrainData.heightmapResolution, terrain.terrainData.heightmapResolution);

 for (int x = 0; x < terrain.terrainData.heightmapResolution; x++)
 {
     for (int z = 0; z < terrain.terrainData.heightmapResolution; z++)
     {
         float dist = Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(x, z), new Vector2(posXInTerrain, posZInTerrain));

         if (dist < deformationRadius)
         {
             float deformation = (deformationRadius - dist) / deformationRadius * deformationAmount;
             heights[x, z] -= deformation;
         }
     }
 }

 terrain.terrainData.SetHeights(0, 0, heights);

}
but it doesn't work.
Help
